# Support for mouse over,mouse out,click in r3d4?

Tags: d3.js, raphael

I am using d3 with raphael to support the lower versions of internet explorer. i almost done with it but i need to have mouse events on my ui but as i am using

```
var d3_raphael = d3.raphael(paper);
```

it's not supporting any event. i tried everything as i am naive.. my code is

```
var node = chart.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(bubble.nodes(stuff).filter(function(d) { 
            return !d.children; 
        }))
    .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx",function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy",function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {return fill(d.packageName); })
            .on("mouseover",function(){alert('heeloo');})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon `;` after setting the fill property. Removing that must solve your problem.